# How to prove that the space of all bounded functions $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Then the space of all bounded functions $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected (where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual metric and $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{R})$ has the topology induced by the sup metric).

I was thinking of finding a subset of B (different from B) and showing that that set is non-empty, open and closed in B, which would imply that B is not connected. What would that subset be? How else could I show that B is not connected?

Answer (score 9):

You will have difficulty proving this, since the space of bounded functions on any set is not only connected, it is even path connected;  two bounded functions $f$ and $g$ may be joined by the path $t\mapsto tf+(1-t)g$.